# ResourceSupport behaves different when Swagger is present

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger, spring-hateoas

I have a class `UserMetasource` extending `ResourceSupport` (from Spring Hateoas):

```
public class UserMetasource extends ResourceSupport {

    public UserMetasource() {
        this.add(linkTo(methodOn(UserController.class).getRoles("roles")));
    }

}
```

Then, in a a controller, I return a `UserMetasource`:

```
@GetMapping("/usermeta")
public UserMetasource getUM() {
    return new UserMetasource();
}
```

This is returning this JSON:

```
{
  links: {
    roles: {
      href: "bla bla bla"
    }
  }
}
```

So good, so far. Now, I have added Swagger to my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And I have annotated the endpoint like this:

```
@GetMapping("/usermeta")
@ApiOperation(value = "Get UM", response = UserMetasource.class)
public UserMetasource getUM() {
    return new UserMetasource();
}
```

and now, JSON returned is this one:

```
{
  _links: {
    roles: {
      href: "bla bla bla"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `_links` starts with underscore. Why is that? Is it possible to avoid that? I want `links` to be always without underscore.

Comment: is it annotating the resource that causes the change, or just importing swagger? what happens if you leave swagger imported but remove  `@ApiOperation(value = "Get UM", response = UserMetasource.class)`

Comment: _" I want links to be always without underscore."_ Are you sure? Because the HAL standard is with underscore, so I would go with that.

Comment: @WillM. Just importing swagger causes the change

Comment: @Héctor try checking your maven dependency tree with and without the import and look for unintended changes.